# SSIS "Execute Process" Exit Code 253

Tags: sql-server, ssis, aws-cli

### General issue *(lots of questions on this already):*

I have an SSIS package that works from Visual Studio, but it fails from SQL Agent.

### Specific Failure Point

- Task: Execute Process
- Executable invoked: aws cli
- Error message: `The process exit code was "253" while the expected was "0".`

### Things I've tried

- Checked permissions on the executable and destination folder. They have execute and read/write permissions (respectively) for the SQL Agent user.
- Looked up exit code 253; I haven't found any documentation on it.
- Stripped away everything but the "Execute Process" task invoking AWS CLI. Still get error 253.
- Multiple AWS CLI Commands (`s3api get-object`, `s3 ls`). Still get error 253.

### Conclusion

My main question is: **what is exit code 253?**

Comment: Here's a [doc link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-returncodes.html) for the AWS cli return codes. "The system environment or configuration was invalid. While the command provided may be syntactically valid, missing configuration or credentials prevented the command from running."

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you! This is the documentation I was looking for. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dan Guzman for pointing me to the [documentation on exit code 253](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-returncodes.html).

### [Exit code 253](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-returncodes.html)

Essentially, AWS CLI configuration isn't right.

> The system environment or configuration was invalid. While the command provided may be syntactically valid, missing configuration or credentials prevented the command from running.

### Why this code was returned

Visual Studio executes as User A (my account), while SQL Agent executes as User B (whatever user it's configured with).

I set up the AWS CLI on my account, but that wasn't enough. I need to configure it for Account B as well.

CLI config details are stored in each user's home directory (`~/.aws/config`, `~/.aws/credentials`). I can navigate to User B's home directory and set up config details there.